# How to create a view in mysql by mapping 3 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[1st table refferal_benifits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TLHn.png)

[2nd table puja_orders_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC322.png)

From the user I will get the puja_order_id in the first table..
I need to map it with 2nd table and I will get puja_id..
Then I need to map puja_id with 3rd table named(pujas) and I will get puja_name..
Here I should create 2 views..
Instead of this how to map 3 tables and get only 1 view??

Comment: Please provide the SQL you have tried with.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this view query:

```
CREATE VIEW your_view_name AS

SELECT * FROM refferal_benifits t1 INNER JOIN puja_order_details t2
ON t1.puja_order_id = t2.puja_order_id
INNER JOIN pujas t3
ON t2.puja_id = t3.puja_id
WHERE t1.puja_order_id = your_id_that_you_want
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a view by three tables 'orders', 'customer' and ' agents' with following conditions -

**1.** 'a' and 'b' and 'c' are the aliases of 'orders' and 'customer' and 'agents' table,

**2.** 'cust_code' of 'orders' and 'customer' table must be same,

**3.** 'agent_code' of 'orders' and 'agents' table must be same,

the following SQL statement can be used :

```
CREATE VIEW ordersview  
AS SELECT ord_num, ord_amount, a.agent_code,  
agent_name, cust_name  
FROM orders a, customer b, agents c  
WHERE a.cust_code = b.cust_code  
AND a.agent_code = c.agent_code;
```